# RFC to get list of activated languages in the SAP system

Tags: abap, saprfc

Is there any RFC to get list of activated languages in my SAP server ?

RFC /GRCPI/GRIA_GET_INSTALLED_LANG is giving the list of installed languages but not the activated ones.

Also, there is a FM /IXOS/DC_H_GET_INST_LANGUAGES which is giving me activated languages list. But I need a RFC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you need *installed* or *installable* languages. For installed languages, use `SWK_SYSTEM_LANGUS_GET`. For installable languages (`T002C-LAINST = 'X'`), you may want to try to use `RFC_READ_TABLE` to access the table `T002C` if there's no other solution.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I want the list of active languages. This RFC gives me  list of all lang. With active languages i mean the language with which i can login the SAP system. While login we pass the lang key.

Comment: there is FM RSAN_SYSTEM_PARAMETER_READ, but it isn't enabled for remote execution. You would have to read profile parameter zcsa/installed_languages (make sure to activate the upper/lower case option in SE37 if you want to test the FM).